# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException Repeatedly Occuring

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I keep having this issue where whenever I try to run my program, it comes up with this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
```

This is the code I currently have:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.text.NumberFormat"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>

 <body>
 <%
 String strValue, strLife;
 strValue=request.getParameter("pValue");
 strLife=request.getParameter("pLife");      
 double value, life, depreciation,totalDepreciation=0;
 value=Double.parseDouble(strValue);
 life=Double.parseDouble(strLife);   
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();   
 depreciation=value/life;
 totalDepreciation=depreciation;
  %>   
 <p>Straight Line Depreciation Table</p>
 <p>Property Value: <input type='text' name='pValue' value='<%=nf.format(value)%>' /></p>
 <p>Property Life: <input type='text' name='pLife' value='<%=life%>'/></p>     
 <table border='1' width='400' cellspacing=1>
    <thead> 
        <tr> <th>Year</th> <th>Value at BeginYr</th>
             <th>Dep During Yr</th> <th>Total to EndOfYr</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
    for (int count = 1; count <= life; count++)
     {
    %>
        <tr>
            <td width='25%'><%=count%></td>
            <td width='25%'><%=nf.format(value)%></td>
            <td width='25%'><%=nf.format(depreciation)%></td>
            <td width='25%'><%=nf.format(totalDepreciation)%></td>
        </tr>
    <% 
    value -= depreciation;
    totalDepreciation+=depreciation;
    } 
    %>      
  </table>
```

What is the reason I am having this issue? The error report is incredibly unhelpful, and I am not finding much help online. Thank you very much!

Comment: If "pValue" and "pLifet" arent in the querystring, that might mess up the parsing

Comment: The querystring? I thought that was the URL. How would I make sure they are in the querystring?

Comment: Yeah, the query string is everything in the URL past the `?`. For example, if you have the URL: `http://www.example.com/some/page.jsp?pValue=something&pLife=somethingElse`, the query string is `pValue=something&pLife=somethingElse`. So my point is that you **must** request your page with a query string that provides values for `pValue` and `pLife`. If you don't provide them, then your lines of code where you do `value=Double.parseDouble(strValue);` will fail, because `strValue` will be empty or null. As long as you're always requesting the URL with those 2 values, then the problem is elsewhere

Comment: How do I even view the URL for the file? I can't even find the querystring to check if it provides those values.